# Element implicitly has type 'any', because expression of type 'any' cannot be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to solve the duplicateCount() function.

Here is my code :

```
export const duplicateCount = (text: string): number => {
  let countObj = {}
  if (text.length === 0) return 0
  let allLetters = text.toLowerCase().split("")
  allLetters.forEach(letter => {
      if(countObj[letter]) {
          countObj[letter] ++
      }else {
          countObj[letter] = 1
      }
  })
}
```

I get an error that says `Element implicitly has type 'any', because expression of type 'string' cannot be used to index type '{}'`. I don't really understand what it mean, can someone explain how to solve it?

Comment: `countObj` is typed as `{}`. `letter` is typed as `string`. `countObj[letter]` could be anything, the compiler doesn't know if `++` will work. Read e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html.

Comment: ok understood. which solution could you recommend to me ?

Comment: Tell the compiler what you actually expect the type of countObj to be, so it doesn't have to try to infer it from an empty object.

Comment: Something like `let countObj: Record<string, number> = {}`

Answer (score 0):

I finally end up with this solution code:

```
export const duplicateCount = (text: string): number => {
  let countObj: Record<string, number> = {}
  let count: number = 0
  if (text.length === 0) return 0
  let allLetters = text.toLowerCase().split("")
  allLetters.forEach((letter) => {
    if (countObj[letter]) {
      countObj[letter]++
    } else {
      countObj[letter] = 1
    }
  })
  for (const key in countObj) {
    if (countObj[key] > 1) {
      count++
    }
  }
  return count
}
```

I'm open for any suggestion refactoring